# Eval string for object structure

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to translate the list of string into a literal object in javascript,
i tried using eval but unfortunately it doesn't work for me or maybe i implemented it wrong

This is my sample list

```
var listOfTempData = [];

listOfTempData.push("retVal.Rate='125.4'");
listOfTempData.push("retVal.OTRateBasis='Current'");
listOfTempData.push("retVal.Name='Holiday OT'");
listOfTempData.push("retVal.Code='HOT101'");
listOfTempData.push("retVal.OvertimeRateType.Code='C72310AE-6'");
```

and i want to create a literal object like this

```
{
  Rate: '125.4',
  OTRateBasis: 'Current',
  Name: 'Holiday OT',
  Code: 'HOT101',
  OvertimeRateType: {
    Code: 'C72310AE-6'
  }
}
```

based on the list of strings from *listOfTempData*

This is what i've done so far

```
var retVal = {};

for(var i = 0 ; i < listOfTempData.length; i++)
{
    eval(listOfTempData[i]);
}
```

any help please.

Comment: A JSON format string would make this trivial, can you change the format?

Comment: Before you can assign to `retVal.OvertimeRateType.Code` you have to do `retVal.OvertimeRateType = {}`.

Comment: A wise man once told me: "If you're using `eval`, you're most likely doing it wrong."

Comment: Instead of using `eval`, parse the template strings. You can then use a loop to assign to the nested properties.

Comment: @Alex K. i wish i can but that list of string is generated via code or is already defined :(

Comment: @SterlingArcher i am thinking also for split('.') then manually looping it then create an instance, i think that would work, is there any way to do it without doing it like that?

Comment: If you eval the whole `listOfTempData` together you could add some code to dump `retVal` to JSON and read that back into your main program...

Comment: Or you could just, you know, parse the thing. Get the property name list and the value string and you just need to parse the value properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you're asking for, with the example code supplied...

```
var listOfTempData = [];

listOfTempData.push("retVal.Rate='125.4'");
listOfTempData.push("retVal.OTRateBasis='Current'");
listOfTempData.push("retVal.Name='Holiday OT'");
listOfTempData.push("retVal.Code='HOT101'");
listOfTempData.push("retVal.OvertimeRateType.Code='C72310AE-6'");

var obj = {};

function addProperty(obj, name, value) {
    if (name.indexOf(".") == -1) {
        obj[name] = value;
    }
    else {
        var name1 = name.split(".")[0];
        var name2 = name.substr(name.indexOf(".") + 1);
        obj[name1] = {};
        addProperty(obj[name1], name2, value);
    }
}

for(var i = 0; i < listOfTempData.length; i++) {
    var data = listOfTempData[i];
    data = data.substr(data.indexOf(".") + 1).split("=");
    addProperty(obj, data[0], data[1]);
}

console.dir(obj);
```

As you can see, it removes `retVal.` from each string and then splits by `=` in order to get the name and value.  With that information it's simple to create an object that represents the data.  It is also recursive so that it finds delimiters in names and splits accordingly.

Here's a working fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/ArchersFiddle/zxsaqjf3/1/

Just run it and check the console for output.

Incidentally, I hate doing things like this - it makes my skin crawl.  All it would take is one change at the data source and your whole application could collapse.  If there is *any* way possible to fix the data source, rather than massage it later, then I would strongly recommend doing that.

Just my 2 cents :)

Comment: Thanks sir, i think this is better solution than using eval

Comment: I could not agree more, and I'm glad I could help :)